# iphone-UIView-Popup

Tags: iphone

I Make One Form Which Show Book Primary Detail In UITableView
When I Select  1 Row The Page Is Navigate To Detail Page...
Which Show Full Detail Of Books...

Now I Want To Pop Up Detail View.. Like UIAlertView...
My FirstPage Stil Visible .
Just Detailpage Is Visible On The FirstPage

Shortly.. I Want To Show UIView Like UIAlertView..(Pop Up)
And Detail Page UIView Is Shown With Small Size

How I Can ?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement your own animations that replicate the alertview animation.

[Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)